# Derivation of conservation laws in differential form

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Consider the derivation of the heat equation e.g. Evans, p. 44.

One starts with an integral conservation law:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_V u \;dx = - \int_{\partial v} F \cdot \nu \;dS \underset{\text{Gauß}}{=} = - \int_V \operatorname{div}F \;dx, \tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $V$ is a smooth subregion of an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

The common argument is that "since $V$ is arbitrary", equation ($\ast$) implies the PDE
$$
u_t = - \operatorname{div} F.
$$

I never understood this argument.
It seems to me that some kind of mean value property could apply.
The only statements I am familiar with and which could help are the [Fundamental lemma of variational calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations) or a theorem of measure theory that in equation ($\ast$) involves all measurable sets $V$ of a $\sigma$-finite measure space. But none of the two statements applies.

Can someone explain to me, if and why this argument holds. Intuitively the statement is clear (making $V$ arbitrarily small) but at the same time just saying that "since $V$ is arbitrary" gives me the feeling I have if I see an incomplete proof.

Can you help me fill the gap and make the argument rigorous?

Comment: Thanks for the suggested edit. I'm sorry it was rejected, such fixes are in principle welcome. Some reviewers however don't always recognise that it's a fix.

Comment: Assuming $F$ is regular enough, apply Gauß' divergence theorem on the right, $$\int_{\partial V} F\cdot \nu\,dS = \int_V \operatorname{div} F \,dx.$$ On the left, assuming $u$ is regular enough, move the differentiation under the integral, $$\frac{d}{dt} \int_V u\,dx = \int_V u_t\,dx.$$ If $u_t$ and $\operatorname{div} F$ are continuous, the equality $\int_V u_t\,dx = - \int_V \operatorname{div} F\,dx$ for all (Euclidean) balls $V$ suffices to conclude $u_t = -\operatorname{div} F$.

Comment: If $u_t$ and $\operatorname{div} F$ are less regular, you need an argument to approximate arbitrary measurable subsets by smooth $V$, to then apply the fundamental lemma of variational calculus. What regularity of $u$ and $F$ is assumed?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for your comments. At the point of deriving the heat equation the author (Evans - PDE) does not assume any regularity. If we assume $u$ and $F$ to be sufficiently regular, I still don't understand how we can derive the equality of the integrands if I don't assume that both integrands fulfill some kind of mean value property, i.e. $u(x) = \frac{1}{|B_r(x)|} \int_{B_r(x)} u(y) dy$.

Comment: If $u_t$ and $\operatorname{div} F$ are continuous, and we have e.g. $u_t(x_0) + \operatorname{div} F (x_0) > 0$ for some $x_0$, then by continuity we have $u_t(x) + \operatorname{div} F(x) > 0$ on some ball $B_\varepsilon(x_0)$, and hence $\int_{B_\varepsilon(x_0)} u_t + \operatorname{div} F\,dx > 0$, in contradiction to the assumption. So we don't need something like the mean value property. However, for every locally integrable function $g$, we have something similar to a mean value property, namely for almost all $x$ we have

Comment: $$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{\lvert B_r(x)\rvert} \int_{B_r(x)} g(y)\,dy = g(x).$$ Apply that to $u_t$ and $\operatorname{div} F$ to conclude that $u_t = -\operatorname{div} F$ almost everywhere, provided $u$ and $F$ are regular enough that you can apply the divergence theorem, and move the differentiation under the integral.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks again!